# 301 URL redirect from one domain to another maintaining full URL

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting

I have two domains - crmpicco.co.uk and ayrshireminis.com - if I browse to:

`www.crmpicco.co.uk/mini/new` I want to be able to redirect to `www.ayrshireminis.com/mini/new`

I am sure I have seen this done before, but i'm not sure if this is a configuration setting or a coding change. Do I need to configure the crmpicco.co.uk domain in someway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run apache you can try this in you .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?crmpicco\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ayrshireminis.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I assume that is the .htaccess file in the DOCROOT of www.crmpicco.co.uk?

Comment: If DOCROOT is the same as WEBROOT then it's correct. (eg. if you create DOCROOT/foo.html it should be accessible from domain.com/foo.html)

Comment: It needs a forward slash before the dollar sign, but it works: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ayrshireminis.com/$1 [R=301,L]